# Disable backref printing with fullcite

Tags: biblatex, back-referencing

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,backref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newbibmacro*{mypageref}{%
\addperiod
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {}
    {\printtext[brackets]{%
      \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
        {\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace}
    {\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}%
      \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}
\renewbibmacro{pageref}{}

\renewbibmacro{finentry}{%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{mypageref}%
  \finentry}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{knuth:ct:e}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This allows the backrefs to be formatted the way I want them (between brackets, etc) but it also prints the backref with the `\fullcite` command. How can I disable backref in the body of the document when using `\fullcite` while preserving backref (and formatting) in the bibliography?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in theory, it would be possible to check whether we're in a cite command, or in the bibliography (with `\ifcitation` and `\ifbibliography`, pp. 185-186 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), that is not really necessary here, as we can just modify the `pageref` macro to do what you want (there is no need for a new `mypageref`) and use the full stop to separate the pagerefs from the rest of the bibliography entry.

```
\renewcommand{\bibpagerefpunct}{\addperiod\space}
\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {}
    {\printtext[brackets]{%<--- here we had parens before
       \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
         {\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace}
         {\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}%
       \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}
```

The standard `pageref` is not used in `\fullcite`s, so we're fine, here.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,backref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand{\bibpagerefpunct}{\addperiod\space}
\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {}
    {\printtext[brackets]{%
       \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
         {\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace}
         {\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}%
       \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{knuth:ct:e}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! One minor questions: how do I add a period after the publisher (or eventually page number) in `\fullcite`?

Comment: @petobens Well, that's standard behaviour, you could redefine the `\fullcite` command to `\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}\finentrypunct}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}` (modulo line breaks, obviously; the change is `\finentrypunct`).