# How to change the format of backref? I want [Cited on page X]

Tags: biblatex, back-referencing

This is a following up question from [backref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202412/disable-backref-printing-with-fullcite)

The MWE output is:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,backref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand{\bibpagerefpunct}{\addperiod\space}
\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {}
    {\printtext[brackets]{%
       \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
         {\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace}
         {\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}%
       \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{knuth:ct:e}

testing \textcite{knuth:ct:e}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

How can I change from

```
[Cit. on p. X]
```

to

```
[Cited on page X]
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text printed for back reference is stored in the bib string `backrefpage` (and the string `backrefpages`). These strings can be localised in the preamble of a document by using `\DefineBibliographyStrings`.

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  backrefpage={Cited on page},
  backrefpages={Cited on pages}
}
```

Comment: thanks. I have a another follow up question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525490/how-to-change-from-cited-on-page-1-2-to-cited-on-pages-1-and-2-in-backref