# How to change from [Cited on page 1, 2] to [Cited on pages 1 and 2] in backref?

Tags: biblatex, back-referencing

This is the following up question from [Change format in backref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524911/how-to-change-the-format-of-backref-i-want-cited-on-page-x)

I would like to change from:
[image]

to

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,backref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  notcited     = {not cited},
  backrefpage={Cited on page},
  backrefpages={Cited on pages}
}


\renewcommand{\bibpagerefpunct}{\addperiod\space}
\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {}
    {\printtext{%
       \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
         {\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace}
         {\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}%
       \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}

\begin{document}

\fullcite{knuth:ct:e}

testing \textcite{knuth:ct:e}

\clearpage

testing \textcite{knuth:ct:e}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Basically from

> Knuth, Donald E. (1986). Computers & Typesetting. Vol. E: Computer Modern Typefaces. Reading, Mass.: Addison-Wesley. Cited on pages 1, 2.

to

> Knuth, Donald E. (1986). Computers & Typesetting. Vol. E: Computer Modern Typefaces. Reading, Mass.: Addison-Wesley. Cited on pages 1 and 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following. It only work with `backrefstyle=none` as otherwise the list will be compressed on the fly and it is not easily possible to figure out which item comes in penultimate position.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,backref=true,backrefstyle=none]{biblatex}


\NewBibliographyString{notcited}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  notcited     = {not cited},
  backrefpage  = {cited on page},
  backrefpages = {cited on pages}
}

\makeatletter
\DeclareListFormat{pageref}{%
  \ifnumless{\abx@pagerefstyle}{0}
    {\usebibmacro{list:delim}{#1}%
     \ifhyperref
       {\hyperlink{page.#1}{#1}}
       {#1}}
    {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
       {\usebibmacro{pageref:init}}
       {}%
     \usebibmacro{pageref:comp}{#1}%
     \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}
       {\usebibmacro{pageref:dump}}
       {}}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\bibpagerefpunct}{\addperiod\space}
\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {}
    {\printtext{%
       \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
         {\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace}
         {\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}%
       \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
testing \textcite{sigfridsson}

\clearpage

testing \textcite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: > Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde (1998). “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P. Cited on pages 1 and 2.]

Comment: thanks. It works well. Brillant! Can I know how you get the code from? I may want to learn it

Comment: @aan The standard definition of `\DeclareListFormat{pageref}` can be found in `biblatex.def`. The definition uses `list:plain` which always typesets `multilistdelim`. In the code above that was changed to the usual `list:delim` so that we get an `finallistdelim`/"and" between the last two items.