# Show [Cited on page X] in natbib

Tags: hyperref, natbib, back-referencing

The questions that I saw online are only for `biblatex` like [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524911/how-to-change-the-format-of-backref-i-want-cited-on-page-x?noredirect=1&lq=1), unfortunately I'm using `natbib` and prefer not to switch.

This are the packages I'm using for references and bibliography:

```
% PACKAGES FOR REFERENCES & BIBLIOGRAPHY
\usepackage[backref=page, colorlinks=true,
 linkcolor=bluepoli, anchorcolor=bluepoli,
 citecolor=bluepoli, filecolor=bluepoli,
 menucolor=black, runcolor=black,
 urlcolor=bluepoli, linktocpage=true,
 pagebackref = true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[square, numbers, sort&compress]{natbib} 
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
```

Right now my output is the following

[image]

But I want something like:

[image]

I tried to search online but I repeat, all the answer seems to work only on bib latex and not on natbib.

Comment: That one is for natbib specifically, you can try if it works for you. If not then you should extend your question here to provide a full compilable example that generates the output that you show. Without that it is difficult and time-consuming to provide an answer that will work in your specific case.

Comment: See also the [backref manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/backref.pdf) for information on how to format the reference, i.e., how to put the exact text _cit. on p._ in the bibliography.

Comment: Thank you Marijn for your answers, actually I have looked at the answer you linked and don't answer my question. My question simply is about: how to print "cited on p. 51" instead of the simple "51".

Comment: I see, I somewhat misinterpreted your question, sorry. Answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `hyperref` option `pagebackref` you can format the backreferences by redefining the command `\backrefalt`, as described on page 4 of the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/backref.pdf) of the backref package (which is loaded when using the hyperref option).

The argument `#1` of `\backrefalt` is the number of backreferences. The `\ifcase` statement in the MWE below checks if this number is 0, 1, or 2+ and formats the backreference(s) accordingly.

Note that you don't need both `backref=page` and `pagebackref=true` as hyperref options, either one of those is sufficient.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
linktocpage=true,
pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[square, numbers, sort&compress]{natbib} 

\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{%
\ifcase #1 %
No citations.%
\or
(cit. on p. #2).%
\else
(cit. on pp. #2).%
\fi
}

\begin{document}
A citation: \cite{article-minimal}.

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you Marijn

Comment: Anyway, I don't know who closed my questions claiming that is already answered in the linked answered but actually it doesn't, the key point for my problem is in your `\renewcommand`, which is not present in the linked answer, so thank you again Marijn

Comment: @paolopazzo sometimes people that vote to close are a bit too enthusiastic, like I was when I suggested the duplicate. I voted to reopen the question, hopefully this will generate a similar amount of enthusiasm :)